# Reset gerrit -2 Code Review

Tags: gerrit

If a user that set -2 on a change is away, how can one forcefully remove the flag to make it possible to submit a change? -2 is will stay even though new patch sets were added, which is perfectly understandable and correct, but in some situations can be a nuisance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these special situations you can remove the reviewer. To remove reviewers who have given negative score you need to be Project owner, Administrator or have the "Remove Reviewer" access right.

See more details [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_remove_reviewer).